# How to obtain a serial number of scanner with TWAIN?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, twain

I would like to obtain the serial number of a scanner in C# using `twain_32.dll`.
I've found out it has to be done with dscap method with the `icap_serialnumber` capability.

Can anyone give me an example how to do this?

Comment: I´m not really sure, but some of the code in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357297/is-it-possible-in-twain-to-force-a-scanner-to-set-the-region-to-the-entire-width may help you.

Comment: when i try the code, i get a failed as return code for the dsmparent statement. 
can any-one tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You have confirmed that your scanner driver supports this capability?  I find it in the TWAIN spec as CAP_SERIALNUMBER (0x1024).  And it is optional - you cannot assume that a scanner supports it.

If you get TWRC_FAILURE when you try to GET that capability, check the condition code.  Your library or component should provide a way to get the condition code after the GET.  A value of TWCC_CAPUNSUPPORTED would mean that the scanner driver does not support that capability.  Other condition codes are described in the TWAIN specification, although sometimes a little imagination is needed to guess what the driver is trying to say...

The [TWAIN Working Group forum](http://twainforum.org) is maybe a little better place for this kind of question.