# Create and Save a Bitmap from an IntPtr c#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, intptr, twain

In my application I scan an image from a TWAIN device, then, I need to save this image to a local disk.
All I have is an IntPtr that references the image byte data array.
How can I create a Bitmap object using the IntPtr value?
I tried with:

```
Bitmap _img = new Bitmap(2450, 2450, 2452, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, pixptr);
_img.Save("c:\\1.Jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This saves the image, but the image is never the same as I scanned.
Any help?

Comment: Are you quite sure that the dimensions and pixel format you specify are correct for the bitmap?

Comment: Are you sure the third parameter for Bitmap ctor is correct?

Comment: Actually, I'm not. I tried with this values, and with higher and lower too, but, I got the same result: An image with a single line, not the one I scanned. I GUESS it's something related to the IntPtr.

Comment: I get the IntPtr from this TWAIN function: DSixfer(appid, srcds, TwDG.Image, TwDAT.ImageNativeXfer, TwMSG.Get, ref hbitmap); Where the hbitmap references the byte data array.

Comment: @HansPassant TWAIN is standard interface and every image viewer uses that so there must be a way to get that image.

Comment: That *hbitmap* is a handle to a bitmap, not an pointer to the pixel data.  Use Image.FromHbitmap() instead.

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that although TWAIN is standard it can produce weird stuff: look at this guy he ended up using cygwin and SANE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357297/is-it-possible-in-twain-to-force-a-scanner-to-set-the-region-to-the-entire-width

Comment: Also, being a HBITMAP, I think you may want to treat it as DIB, Device Independent Bitmap. Which has different memory layout and format than the bitmap *file* format. The header section differs in some places, all because it is device independent.

Comment: if you just wanna save the bitmap, you can import gdiplus.dll, and use the method GdipSaveImageToFile. This is more convenient.

Comment: The IntPtr refers to a DIB that you need to render as a Bitmap.  Look at the BitmapRenderer class at https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet/blob/master/src/TwainDotNet/Win32/BitmapRenderer.cs

Comment: Are you sure you have a right stride? Shouldn't it be 2450 as well?